# Get delimited data from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a table named `TBL_SUBACC` and fields are: `Account, Branch, Ftype, ArmCode,DrlsttrDate, CrlsttrDate, TelNo` etc.

Currently I am getting `|` separated data using following query:

```
select account +'|'+ branch +'|' + armcode as delimited_data from
   ReportingFramework.dbo.TBL_SUBACC
```

This gives the result as:

```
    delimited_data
    111123|01|C0013
    111124|01|C0013
    1234121|05|C0324
    0120219|02|C0329
    0212108|03|C3232
    111121|01|C0013
```

This is exactly what I want. But, the above query requires all the fileds name to be given manually.
I want to get delimited data of all fields without giving all column names.

How can I do `select *` to get delimited data from the table?

Comment: just specify the column name. what's the problem with it?

Comment: @JW웃 there is no other option without specifying column names?

Comment: it seems that your request works fine. why do you want to improve it?

Comment: @YuliaV In the table, there are more than 50 columns, and it is time consuming job to specify all column names.. so

Comment: what software are you using? in SSMS you can generate SELECT request with all column names by doing 1 right click, then you can just copy-paste...

Comment: What happens to the delimited data after you have produced it? If i gets consumed by an application, you could move the logic to the application.

Comment: AS @YuliaV suggests, you could generate the SELECT statement. Then use Find and Replace to replace the commas in the SELECT list with +'|'+.

Comment: @YuliaV Yup, I am using SSMS.

Comment: @Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ It goes to the IT Department of Bank.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @nsql nvarchar(max);
set @nsql = '
select ' + stuff((
    select '+''|''+isnull(cast(' + quotename(name) + ' as nvarchar(max)),'''') '
    from sys.columns
    where object_id=object_id('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
    order by column_id
    for xml path(''), type).value('/','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 5, '') + ' as delimited_data
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
--print @nsql;
exec (@nsql);
```

Replace YOUR_TABLE_NAME (twice) with your target table. To do it properly, you need to cater for conversion to VARCHAR and NULLs.  This works very poorly for datetimes, which come out in the terrible format for pipe-delimited consumption by another software.  Better if you just stop at `print @nsql` and hand-tweak that before running.

Comment: It says `Command(s) completed successfully.` but I can't see the data.

Comment: Have you actually replaced 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' with, well, your table name?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.test'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT delimited_data = ' + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ' + ''|'' + ' + 
    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 
        THEN 'ISNULL(CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'''') '
        ELSE 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))'
    END
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, CHAR(13)) + '
FROM ' + @table_name

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT delimited_data = 
             CAST([WorkOutID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     + '|' + CAST([DateOut] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     + '|' + CAST([EmployeeID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     + '|' + CAST([DepartmentUID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     + '|' + ISNULL(CAST([WorkPlaceUID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
     + '|' + ISNULL(CAST([CategoryID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
FROM dbo.test
```